# Full page layout in HTML with scrolling center

Tags: html, layout

I have a requirement to produce a HTML layout as follows:

1. The page should flow to occupy the available space in the browser window
2. It should have a fixed height header and footer
3. The central area should occupy the remaining height
4. The central area is broken into three columns. Each of these colums should be independently scrollable should the content exceed the available area.

I've had a go at this using a table of height 100% (works eventually with a bit of tweaking) with the top and bottom cells having fixed heights. This leaves the central area to occupy the remaining space. This area contains another table with three columns. Each cell contains a div with height and width set to 100% and overflow set to auto. It seems like it should work but excess content simply causes the main table to extend its height so that the whole page becomes scrollable.

Does anyone know of any examples of this working in practice? The solution is expected to be *reasonably* cross browser but doesn't have to cover every corner case.

Thanks,
Phil

**Update**
I figured out a solution and posted it as an answer here.

Comment: Your "update" should go as an answer, not as a modification to the question.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't noticed that you can answer your own question.

Comment: By "should flow to occupy the available space", do you mean that it should have 100% height all the time, or that it should expand with the content?

Comment: @You, I mean that it should be 100% height all of the time (meaning 100% of the browser window). If the content in #center is larger than that space, then it should be scrollable. Likewise for #left and #right.

Comment: There you go, non-table answer provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Note:** I'm assuming HTML5 and CSS3 here, but kept to properties that work in most browsers. The HTML5 can easily be exchanged for HTML 4.01.*

---

To create the kind of layout you want, we start with some basic HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <header> Header </header>
  <div id="content">
    <section id="left"> Left </section>
    <section id="center"> Center </section>
    <section id="right"> Right </section>
  </div>
  <footer> Footer </footer>
</div>
```

The difficulty is styling this according to your needs. Starting out by setting a 100% height on as much as possible, along with suitable overflow values, we can obtain something very close to what you want:

```
html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#wrapper { height: 100%; }
header, footer { height: 50px; }
#content { height: 100%; overflow: hidden; }
section { float: left; overflow: auto; height: 100%; }
#left, #right { width: 100px; }
#center { width: 300px; }
```

Unfortunately, this makes the layout exactly 100px (the combined height of footer and header) too tall. To remedy this, we must decrease the height of `#content` by the same amount, but the standard box model doesn't allow for this. Enter the [`box-sizing`](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201104/controlling_width_with_css3_box-sizing/) (which [is supported by all major browsers except IE7](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing)), which we can use to change the box model being used. With the `border-box` box model, padding is included in the height and as such we can "remove" the necessary height from `#content`:

```
#content { -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -ms-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 50px 0; margin: -50px 0; }
```

See also [this JSfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/urdh/uM9HT/1/) and [the full screen result](http://jsfiddle.net/urdh/uM9HT/1/embedded/result/) for further details.

Comment: I am glad to see that you redeemed yourself. :-)

Comment: @You, thank you for taking the time to post a solution. It works beautifully on Chrome. With regard to other browsers, IE 8 and Firefox 3.6 both have some problems although it's possible that IE9 and FF4+ will handle this correctly.

Answer (score 1):

There are several examples of this type of layout available. One of the best is Matthew Levine's "Holy Grail," [complete with tutorial](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/holygrail).

[image: Holy Grail template]

You will note that this layout does not fix the footer at the bottom of the screen. You can do this by setting `body` (or an all-encompassing div) height to 100% and using `overflow:hidden` but this introduces potential usability issues. You may find that it is best to let your page expand to correct height as needed.

Comment: Hi George, thanks for your suggestion. As you mention, it doesn't fix the footer and I wasn't able to achieve the required effect (I want left, right and center to be independently scrollable). I've posted an update to my original question which might help guide someone else, I appreciate your input though.

Answer (score -1):

I figured out *a* solution, it's not elegant but it does work. I created a table set to 100% height. I then added a function which executes on load and resize. This gets the height of the window and subtracts from it, the height of the header and footer, it then sets the height of a div in the central area to be that remaining height. The main difficulty was coming up with an accurate window height, through various bits of googling, I came up with the following which appears to work fine:

```
function getWindowHeight() {
   var height = 0;
   var body = window.document.body;

   if (window.innerHeight) {
        height = window.innerHeight;
   } else if (body.parentElement.clientHeight) {
       height = body.parentElement.clientHeight;
   } else if (body && body.clientHeight) {
       height = body.clientHeight;
   }
   return height;
```

}

Comment: @You: Presumably you know of a way to do this without tables.

Comment: @Chris: "Not nice"? I'm not here to be nice. In my opinion, using tables for layout is completely verboten, and as such this isn't a good answer. Thus, I downvote.

Comment: @You: Being right can trump being nice but you haven't brought anything to the discussion. If you know of a way to do this without tables then feel free to post it. There are some problems which can only be solved with tables and it's up to individuals to decide what to do under those circumstances. Posting a solution gives others the possibility to *choose* what to do under such circumstances.

Comment: @PhilDin: "*There are some problems which can only be solved with tables*"? No. Especially not with the CSS table `display` values.

Comment: @You: `display: table-*` would hardly have solved matters, owing to (a) poor browser support (meaning "not supported absolutely everywhere") and more importantly (b) no behaviour to match the `colspan` attribute. Even in browsers supporting `display: table-*`, the lack of colspan and rowspan make it so that there are many problems indeed which cannot be solved in CSS without tables (or without excessive nastiness/flimsiness).